# How to get parent record Id

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have two objects `A` and `B`.

`A` is master and `B` is detail object. In object `A`, I have a record. When I open that record and scroll down, in related list, we have list of child objects and a new button.

When I create a new child record from Object `A` related list by clicking new button, it will redirect to VF page. I have controller for this VF page. So my requirement is to get the Object `A` record id to controller.

Answer (score 1):

The New button which you have overridden is a **List button**.

To get the record Id of Object A, you have to use the **Standard Controller of Object A** and an extension controller.

Extension controller:

```
 public class ExtenstionController{

    public ExtenstionController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        id_obejctA = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    }
}
```

VisualForcePage:

```
<apex:page standardController="ObjectA" recordSetVar="applications" extensions="ExtenstionController">
    <!-- Implementation -->
<apex:page>
```

Refer [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_composite_app_create_custom_list_button_try_it_out.htm) for creating custom list buttons.

Comment: I forgot to inform that, Here object A is standard object and object B is custom object.

Comment: Try the above code with standard and extensions controller.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit the new button on Detail page of object A, it'll redirect to B's page with the Parent Id of A stored in the URL in `retUrl` variable. From there you can access `retUrl`'s value through the following lines of code.

```
String str = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('retURL').substring(1,16);
Id myId = (Id)str;
```

Now, myId variable of Id type will now contain the record Id of parent (ie, in your case A).